# Retornar resultado Mysql como ranking

Tags: php, mysql

Como devo proceder nesta consulta, onde tenho um cadastro de usuários, e cada usuário envia varias fotos para uma outra tabela, cada foto enviada recebe uma pontuação de 1 a 5

Eu preciso trazer os 10 com o maior numero de pontos e seus respectivos pontos

O campo de pontuação tem o nome de **pontuacao_foto**

```
SELECT * FROM t_login JOIN t_fotos ON id_login = id_login_foto LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode dar uma luz, pense também em usar subSelects

SELECT *, MAX(pontuacao_foto) 
FROM t_login 
JOIN t_fotos ON id_login = id_login_foto 
GROUP BY id_login_foto 
ORDER BY Count(pontuacao_foto) DESC 
LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Acho que isso não resolve, acho que ele precisa que ordene pela soma total de pontos que cada usuário tem com as fotos.

Comment: Exatamente @BrunoHenrique

Comment: @Giba, sim, com uma pequena adaptação, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t_login.id_login, SUM(t_fotos.pontuacao_foto) 
FROM t_login JOIN t_fotos ON id_login = id_login_foto 
ORDER BY 2, 1 DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```